# On the solution to stochastic differential equations and Ito's lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

In [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-6/issue-1/On-the-Gap-Between-Deterministic-and-Stochastic-Ordinary-Differential-Equations/10.1214/aop/1176995608.full) article, Sussmann shows there is a simple link between SDE of the form
$$\tag{1}
\mathrm{d}x=f(x)\mathrm{d}t+g(x)\mathrm{d}w
$$
and their correspondent ODE, provided $f$ and $g$ satisfies some regularity conditions.
But then...what is Ito lemma good for, if every SDE of this form can be solved with the same method as any other ODE?

Comment: Ito's lemma isn't used exclusively for solving SDEs...

Comment: Could you please give me some other areas of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article doesn't discuss time-dependent coefficients

$$\mathrm{d}x=f(t,x)\mathrm{d}t+g(t,x)\mathrm{d}w,$$

where Itô-lemma applies.